# Spring kafka 2.2 type mappings class loader mismatch

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I'm trying to use the new type mappings feature introduced in Spring Kafka 2.2 :

Scroll down to "Mapping Types" :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#serdes

On the producer side, I registered a mapping as follow :

```
senderProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
senderProps.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "foo:com.myfoo.Foo");
```

And on the consumer as follow :

```
consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
consumerProps.put(JsonDeSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "foo:com.yourfoo.Foo");
```

However, when sending an event to Kafka on the producer side of the `com.myfoo.Foo` class, the classId header that is added to the record is `com.myfoo.Foo` instead of `foo`. Thus on the consumer side, it fails to deserialize because `com.myfoo.Foo` is unknown.

I have narrowed the issue down to this method in spring-kafka :

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/converter/AbstractJavaTypeMapper.java#L142

```
protected void addHeader(Headers headers, String headerName, Class<?> clazz) {
    if (this.classIdMapping.containsKey(clazz)) {
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(headerName, this.classIdMapping.get(clazz)));
    }
    else {
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(headerName, clazz.getName().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }
}
```

When debugging through the execution of the serialization of a kafka record, the execution actually goes to the else branch, whereas in my understanding it should actually go to the if branch and add `foo` as a header. Instead it adds `com.myfoo.Foo` to the header.

The culprit seems to be related to a class loader mismatch but I'm not sure if it's actually a bug or something stupid I did on my end.

Basically, the `classIdMapping` map is correctly filled with `com.myfoo.Foo` as a key and the UTF-8 byte[] representation of `foo` as the corresponding value.

However during the if chec, the `clazz` parameter is a Class loaded by a different class loader as what was stored in the `classIdMapping` map, thus the hashcodes are different and it goes to the else branch.

Is it actually a bug on the String-Kafka side or did I misconfigured something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indeed looks like an omission in our implementation. Please, raise an issue for Spring for Apache Kafka project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka. Our idea is do not use `Class<?>` for mapping, but its *Fully Qualified Class Name*.

It seems your application is multi-classloader, e.g. it is Web one. And Apache Kafka Client loads that `senderProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);` in its ClassLoader meanwhile everything else is done by the application context ClassLoader.

As a workaround, meanwhile we fix the issue, we suggest to use a `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` configuration with its `setValueSerializer()` to populate a `JsonSerializer` bean reference. This way you need to populate class mapping via its `setTypeMapper()` and, therefore, a `setIdClassMapping()` on the `DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper`.

Comment: Thanks, reposted under https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/894

Comment: While this is easy enough to fix on the producer side by using the class name instead of the `Class<?>` itself; I don't see a solution on the consumer side (aside from the application injecting the deserializer into the consumer factory). If the deserializer is loaded  by a different classloader, the application will get a `ClassCastException` when trying to access the value of the `ConsumerRecord`. What am I missing?